# how to protect the x++ source code

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a way to protect or hide custom code written in X++ for AX customization. I have made some new custom Forms, Tables, ...etc, on AX and i would like to hide the source code of my customizatzaion.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You can only protect you code by using the correct layers.

You could always scramble/obfuscate your code, there are tools that do this like this one:
http://www.aximprove.co.uk/

However hiding your code or scrambling it is a bad idea. It goes agains everything AX stands for. When you create a product as an ISV, you partners have the right to extends that functionality for their customers. And when a customer wants to customize the solution that the partner provided, they also should be able to do that when they have the correct license. That would be impossible when the code is scrambled. 
Also, imagine debugging that code...
No customer/partner should accept that a solution written in X++ is scrambled.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. From whom are you trying to hide the code?

One solution to hide your code would be to completely remove the layer (.aod file) that you created your customizations on. However, this would take all of your modifications out of the application along with the code.

The only way to keep source code hidden from another user is to make sure that they do not have an X++ Source Code security license on their application.

Comment: thank you for ur ans.i want  obfuscate the x++ source code.and then add the obfuscated code to AOT in ax2012.pls ans...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can't. The X++ code in Dynamics AX is open by definition and there is no way to obfuscate or lock the source code for users or another partners if they have a development license.

You have your code protected by layers, but it is impossible by definition to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can only obfuscate your code.  If you want to keep functionality private, you can put code in a .NET assembly.

Like Klaas said, almost no customer would accept this.  I personally wouldn't accept the code, and I work for a large customer.  I need to be able to debug immediately.  If your code causes an issue that stops our production, that's $150k/hour...that's why I'm on-site and available 24/7.  I doubt you can provide that guarantee too.

Comment: (plus you can just ilSpy the .net anyway)